# Geolocation does not work - how to fix that?

Tags: android, geolocation, ionic3

Please do not mark it as a duplicate question, because the various situations I have seen and dozens of suggestions have failed in my case. Which is very tiring and frustrating.

I have an application made in Ionic that needs to use Geolocation. I followed the ionic documentation and it works great in the browser. But on Android, not! Which is ridiculous from my point of view, since such a basic feature does not work on such a widespread framework as Ionic. Leaving aside the complaint, this is my code:

```
  getLocation() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge: 0
      };

      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((resp) => {
        resolve(resp.coords);
       }).catch(() => {
         resolve(undefined);
       });
    });
  }
```

The problem is that the above routine does not return nor in THEN much less in CATCH when I install the application on Android, which is exactly the same complaint from many other developers. However, as I mentioned, the various tips did not work.

Can someone help me solve this cause? Or even suggest another way? I have already tried navigator, pure javascript, etc. In all this I was not able to resolve this problem.

Comment: So what does the stacktrace from the crash look like?

Comment: Do you have the permissions for it? What's in ```this.geolocation```? Have you consider using [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `timeout` to the `GeolocationOptions`.

```
let options = { 
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 20000 
  };
```